# Duda sobre stderr y fprintf

Tags: c

Buenas tengo una duda y no sé el uso que se le da a **stderr** de la librería de **stdio.h** y  **fprintf()** de **string.h**. Por ejemplo tengo esto:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Error en planta de Centro: %d\n", numeroPlantas);
```

Donde numeroPlantas es un **int**.
Me gustaría que me aclarasen cuando se suelen usar y su significado a ser posible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[fprint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm)** no creo que tengas problema en saberlo, permite que la salida de printf pueda escribirse en cualquier archivo.

> **fprint** Los programadores suelen utilizarlo para imprimir errores, pero
>   puede funcionar con cualquier archivo abierto con la función fopen.

**[stderr](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_error_handling.htm)** es una forma de imprimir los errores, **stderr contiene los errores posibles que el usuario quiere reportar**.

> **stderr** es, como su nombre indica, la salida estandar de errores. este
>   es util cuando por ejemplo, rediriges la salida de tu programa a un
>   archivo. si en ese caso ocurre algun error en la ejecucion del
>   programa y tienes puesta su salida por stderr, el error saldra en la
>   terminal en vez de en el archivo.

[Aquí existe una documentación en español](http://monocaffe.blogspot.mx/2008/04/stderr-stdout-y-ms.html)

como ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int errno ;

int main () {

   FILE * pf;
   int errnum;
   pf = fopen ("archivo_no_existente.txt", "rb");

   if (pf == NULL) { //Archivo no existe!
      errnum = errno;
      //Imprime salida formateada del error.
      fprintf(stderr, "Error al tratar de abrir el archivo es : %s\n", strerror( errnum ));
   }
   else {
      fclose (pf);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Se tiene como salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys , me sirvió mucho. Ya lo te entendí.Saludos

Comment: Que bien amigo, excelente , saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando ejecutas un programa la salida que ves por consola suele ser la combinacióm de stdout y stderr. Pero es posible redirigir ambas salidas a ficheros diferentes.

Así, si ejecutas "./miprograma 1>log 2>errorLog" obtendrás todo lo que imprimas por stderr en errorlog y no en log. Esto asumiendo que el Sistema Operativo asocie 0 con stdin, 1 con stdout y 2 con stderr, que es lo habitual.